# Acceder a sub nodo XML usando xPathfactory Java

Tags: java, xml, nodos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente estoy gestionando un XML con las clases de Java DocumentBuilder y xPathfactory.

Con la expresión:

XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//link[@title="GdD"]");

Consigo acceder al nodo donde title="GdD", pero ¿Existe alguna expreción para acceder al <d:Name>?

No encuentro nada, gracias!

UPDATE, este sería el trozo de XML:

```
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/GdD" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="GdD" href="Web/Lists(guid'f0d1e10d-de9e-47a4-a454-a7d6542e88e4')/Items(2347)/GdD">
            <m:inline>
                <entry>
                    <id>c3a154cb-1b84-47e2-b404-766064bf0a7a</id>
                    <category term="SP.Data.UserInfoItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
                    <title />
                    <updated>2021-09-24T09:28:17Z</updated>
                    <author>
                        <name />
                    </author>
                    <content type="application/xml">
                        <m:properties>
                            <d:Name>i:0#.w|tesa\t152473</d:Name>
                            <d:Title>JOSE SALVADOR ORTEGA CAYUELA</d:Title>
                        </m:properties>
                    </content>
                </entry>
            </m:inline>
        </link>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues ya encontré la solución:

```
xpath.compile("//link[@title=\"GdD\"]/inline/entry/content/properties/Name")
```

Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que implementar https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext.html e utilizar https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#setNamespaceContext-javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext-, para declarar que el prefijo `d` se resuelva al URL dado en tu ejemplo (no puedo copiar la dirección/URL porque solo has insertado una imagen en lugar de un fragmento de XML). Entonces puedes utilizar `d:Name` en la expresión de XPath.